# After upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04, hardware acceleration is gone on Intel Graphics

Tags: upgrade, 18.04

This is on an Intel Skylake machine (Dell XPS 13 - 9350). It worked nicely on 16.04. Now, glxinfo and System Information report "llvmpipe" (software rasterizer). How can I debug this problem?

Comment: Did you try looking for something in the log files?

Comment: Do you have the same issue if you use Wayland instead of X?

Comment: No idea about Wayland, as that's not used by default on 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by uninstalling Unity (which is not needed on 18.04).

By removing /etc/X11/Xsession.d/50_check_unity_support this bug is fixed.

Also see https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1767468